# How do I hide the code for the chart data in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have seen websites that use jquery chart programs and if you do a right click -> view source you cannot see the data for their charts.

How do I do this with highcharts?

Since the code is javascript I figure it's a matter of hiding javascript.  Can you load it from an external file?  Or if ther is any other way of keeping the data from appearing in the source in highcharts how do you do it?

Comment: Yes, you can of course include JS from an external file with `<script>` tags in the head. Also, you can instantiate Highcharts completely from an Ajax-retrieved JSON object. [They even have a demo with Ajax data loading](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax).

Comment: neither of which will prevent a savvy user from downloading the external script file or inspecting the AJAX request manually in the console. bottom line is you cannot hide your data

Comment: I know it won't completely hide it, I just want something a little more secure than having it there in the .html.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of hiding code, when someone can compare your chart with i.e public and reproduce your chart ?

Comment: I have seen it done on other sites and I would like to do something like that on my site.

Comment: Could you show example of such site? Sorry, but Highcharts is written in JS and it's not possible to hide HTML elements for site from user.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to load the chart via ajax.

But this is not anything that can be considered remotely 'secure', nor is there any way to present your data on the web and yet not let people see your data on the web...

In fact, the concept is quite silly...

Comment: Source can be get by console / developers tools, as well ;)